# Pointcut for classes inside different package or sub-packages marked Deprecated and at the time whenever they used or instantiated?

Tags: aop, aspect, pointcut

I want to write a point cut for class instantiation in various packages,like classes inside the subpackages inside com.kepler.xenon (eg.com.kepler.xenon.modules.ticklers.pojo.Tickler,
com.kepler.xenon.modules.product.pojo.Product etc).

```java
//This is my advice
@Aspect
@Component
public class OxAspect {
@After("execution(* com.oxane.xenon..*new(..)) && @within(java.lang.Deprecated)")
public void myAdvice(final JoinPoint jp){
    System.out.println(jp.getSignature().getName()+""+jp.getTarget().getClass());
 }
}
```

```java
//This is my class
package com.kepler.xenon.modules.ticklers.pojo;
@Deprecated
public Class Ticklers{
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "TICKLERS_ID", table = "ID_GENERATOR", pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY", valueColumnName = "GEN_VALUE", pkColumnValue = "TICKLERS_ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TICKLERS_ID")
@Column(name = "TICKLERS_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int ticklersId;

@Column(name = "TASK", nullable = false, length = 256)
private String taskName;

public int getTicklersId() {
    return ticklersId;
}

public void setTicklersId(int ticklersId) {
    this.ticklersId = ticklersId;
}

public String getTaskName() {
    return taskName;
}

public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}

}
```

What i want is that if anyone tries to access the class which is deprecated,then pointcut filters that call and triggers advice.
I have done it for methods but i am failing to do it for classes.

I am adding aspect which works for methods,controller and Dao

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class OxAspect {

private final OxAspectService oxAspectService;

public OxAspect(OxAspectService oxAspectService) {
    this.oxAspectService=oxAspectService;
}

@Pointcut("execution(@java.lang.Deprecated * com.oxane.xenon..*(..))"
        + " || execution(* com.oxane.xenon..*.*(..)) && @within(java.lang.Deprecated)")
public void deprecated() {
}

@Before("deprecated()")
public void log(final JoinPoint jp) {
    oxAspectService.logDeprecatedMethod(jp);
}

}
```

Edit:
I have done some research on spring io and found that it can't be done using spring aop. I have to use load time weaving or compile time weaving to achieve what i want. For that i have to use pure aspect j implementation. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What is "it" you have done for methods and are failing to do for classes. Be more specific, please, and ideally extend your snippets into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating what works and what does not. I would like to see something I can actually run.

Comment: I wanted to paste my whole pojo, but it didn't seem right to me. So i left my Ticklers class empty. Even then it should not be difficult to reproduce, i will add a field, and constructor above from my original code if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for extending the source code. It does not answer my previous question, though. I repeat: What is "it" you have done for methods and are failing to do for classes? I do not understand from your explanation what it is exactly that you got working with methods but not with classes. Are you referring to where you put the annotation, e.g. on methods or classes? You can intercept annotated methods but not methods within annotated classes?

Comment: Like i said, if i mark method,controller and service @Deprecated(with different pointcut), Pointcut catches it with no problem. But as soon as i try to write pointcut for Pojo, nothing happens. For clarity i will put pointcut  for method,services and dao(spring beans).

Comment: Maybe it is my mistake that I do not understand your English, I am sorry for that. But why would it not work with Spring AOP? Are you trying to intercept non-Spring classes, i.e. classes which are not `@Component`s or otherwise wired as Spring beans? In that case your assumption would be correct, for non-Spring classes you have to use an AOP framework which is not dependent on Spring mechanisms, i.e. AspectJ.

Comment: Now you are getting me, i am trying to intercept pojo(classes marked as @Entity only). I thought i can write a poincut to intercept them when ever they get instantiated like new SomeClass(). Can you give me a link or something where i can see aspect j under work(example).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I will devide `@Pointcut` to signle condition like below:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.oxane.xenon..*(..))")
public void anyClassInSubpackage() {
}

@Pointcut("@annotation(java.lang.Deprecated)")
public void deprecatedClass() {
}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.oxane.xenon..*new(..))")
public void anyMethodInSubpackege() {
}

@Pointcut("@within(java.lang.Deprecated)")
public void deprecatedMethod() {
}

@Before("(anyClassInSubpackage() && deprecatedClass()) || (anyMethodInSubpackege() && deprecatedMethod())")
public void myAdvice(final JoinPoint jp){
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: I have combined that in my final code initially for test purpose i was using

`@Pointcut("execution(* com.oxane.xenon..*new(..))")
public void anyMethodInSubpackege() {
}`
but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: try with `@Pointcut("execution(* com.oxane.xenon..*.new(..))")`